# MacBook Air with retina display resolution question

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution

I recently purchased a new MacBook Air with the 2560 x 1600 display. I noticed my resolution didn't appear to be even 1080 when I was connecting to some Windows remote sessions, so I started poking around in the display settings, and the highest it will scale to is 1680 x 1050. I can appreciate why you wouldn't want to go much higher than that since everything would be tiny, but I am wondering if there is a way to force macOS High Sierra on the 2018 MacBook Air to allow Microsoft Remote Desktop to render a remote session at least 1920 x 1080?

Comment: And you did read this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471

Comment: We strongly suggest one question per question. Is there a reason to not have you ask what the reasons are in a second question (so that the opinions can be aired on that) and keep the practical how to force question to live here?

Comment: I had read the Apple article, but thank you for responding. I didn't find it particularly helpful, other than to confirm there might not be a way to force it to display at native resolution. And thanks for the suggestion about making this only one question.